# Network routing issue after connecting to VPN

Tags: vpn, bind

This is how my home network is configured:

1. Internet connects to Router.
2. Bind runs on a dedicated home server (called **plug**).
3. Router is configured to use **plug** as DNS servers.

Till today morning everything was working fine - any devices connected to my home network could access internal websites and the Internet as well without issues or additional configuration.

**This is what I did today morning:**

Connected to VPN to download something. Meanwhile I decided to assign a static IP to my phone so that way time I need to transfer files over **XENDER** application I don't need to look for the IP. Also I thought of assigning domain name (internal) to my phone. So I logged into plug (vpn was still connected) and added a name "phone.internal" to bind configuration so that it points to an static IP. Then I logged into my modem and configured static IP for my phone's mac address. Somewhere in between this is disconnected the VPN also. I restarted bind, plug, modem and my computer. 
Now any device attached to my home network isn't able to connect to my internal websites. It now works only of I manually update the DNS servers to be used on the connecting device. Before this problem occurred I never had to manually configure DNS on any connecting device. It simply used to work.

As a debugging measure, I tried the below command on two of my devices:

```
dig something.internal
```

And **dig** is picking up the proper DNS and IP. But when I try the same using browser it is not able to connect and show the page!!

It works only if I manually configure DNS on my connecting device.

Because I was connected to the VPN, is it possible something (some cache or something) might have changed at the **plug** due to which this is happening?

*Note: VPN was connected only on my laptop. So my plug wasn't in the VPN.*

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When I updated bind with a domain name for my phone, I used an underscore in the name (matt_). When I removed the underscore and restarted bind9 it worked. So I am guessing _ is some kind of reserved key.

Config with issue:

```
matt_    A    IN    192.168.1.5
```

After fix:

```
mattp    A    IN    192.168.1.5
```

I still don't understand why bind9 didn't thow any error on starting. Given that not error was thrown, I still don't understand why the other definitions in the file also stopped working for the period.